# Update parent component in react native from component attached to scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have scroll view in my `HomeScreen` with my `measures` that is array of `Measure` component.

```
<ScrollView>{measures}</ScrollView>
```

My `Measure` component looks like this:

```
class Measure extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View key={this.props.keyval}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteItem(this.props.val.measure_id)}>
          <Text style={styles.measure}>
            ID: {this.props.val.measure_id}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  deleteItem(id) {
    // delete item
    );
  }
}
```

My question is, how to notify parent component `HomeScreen` that `Measure` was deleted to reload scroll view items? Or Maybe you have better idea how to:

1. display measures
2. delete one in `onPress` item
3. reload items in scroll view

Thans for any advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it should be something like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    measures: []
  };

  handleDelete = (id) => {
    // item was deleted
  }

  render() {
    const { measures } = this.state;

    const measuresList = measures.map(measure => (
      <Measure 
         key={measure.measure_id}
         onDelete={this.handleDelete}
         val={measure}
      />
    ));

    return (
     <ScrollView>{measuresList}</ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


class Measure extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View key={this.props.keyval}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteItem(this.props.val.measure_id)}>
          <Text style={styles.measure}>
            ID: {this.props.val.measure_id}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  deleteItem(id) {
    const { onDelete } = this.props;
    // delete item
    onDelete(id); //will call parent method.
  }
}
```

Comment: It feels kinda great, but how to pack `measures` from your code into `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using FlatList as it render only those items which are visible. Much better in terms of performance, especially in big lists taken from API.

Example:

```
<FlatList
  data={measures}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Measure 
    id={item.id} 
    anyOtherNeededPropsKey={anyOtherNeededPropsValue}
  />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an additional property onDelete to the Measure and call it in deleteItem method

Comment: could you provide your answet with some example code?